# C++11 threads with shared mutex and class instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Hello I am experimenting with C++11 and threads. I am facing some problems I can't figure out how to solve. I want to do stuff of a class in another thread and need to use a mutex in several functions and the class.
Yes I know std::mutex is not copyable but I do not know how to solve my problem.

What I have so far is
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include "ThreadClass.h"

void thread_without_class(std::mutex &mutex);
void thread_without_class2(int number, std::mutex &mutex);

int main(int argc, char** argv){    
std::mutex mutex;

ThreadClass *threadClass = new ThreadClass();

std::thread t1(thread_without_class, &mutex);
std::thread t2(thread_without_class2, 10, &mutex);
std::thread t3(thread_without_class2, 11, &mutex);
std::thread t4(threadClass);

threadClass->mutex = mutex;
threadClass->numberOfOutputsI = 5;
threadClass->ThreadOutput();

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();

delete threadClass;
return 0;
}


void thread_without_class(std::mutex &mutex){
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
std::cout << "c++11 thread without anything" << std::endl;
}

void thread_without_class2(int number, std::mutex &mutex){
for (auto i=0; i<number; i++){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << "c++11 thread with function parameter: " << number << std::endl;
}
}
```

ThreadClass.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>

class ThreadClass{
public:
ThreadClass(void);
~ThreadClass(void);
void ThreadOutput();

std::mutex mutex;
int numberOfOutputsI;
};
```

ThreadClass.cpp

```
#include "ThreadClass.h"
#include <iostream>

ThreadClass::ThreadClass(void){
numberOfOutputsI = 0;
}

ThreadClass::~ThreadClass(void){
}

void ThreadClass::ThreadOutput(){
for (auto i=0; i<numberOfOutputsI; i++){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << "I am a class called as a thread" << std::endl;
}}
```

Comment: You have no problem, if you do not formulate the problem.

Comment: I am sorry my problem is how to start a new instance of a class as thread?
My second problem was how to share mutexes with classes and functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want copy, but a reference/pointer:

```
class ThreadClass{
    //..
    std::mutex* mutex = nullptr;
};
```

And in `main`:

```
threadClass->mutex = &mutex;
```

Comment: @user2807083: Depend of the guaranty of lifetime of the mutex.

Comment: Why don't you use RAII instead of raw pointer?

Comment: @Maf: `ThreadClass` doesn't own the mutex, [`std::experimental::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) might be used instead a raw (non-owning) pointer.

Answer (score 1):

you may only pass references into threads with std::ref():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class ThreadClass{
public:
    ThreadClass(std::mutex& m) : mutex(m) {};
    void ThreadOutput();

    std::mutex& mutex;
    int numberOfOutputsI = 0;
};

void ThreadClass::ThreadOutput(){
    for (auto i=0; i<numberOfOutputsI; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << "I am a class called as a thread" << std::endl;
    }
}


void thread_without_class(std::mutex &mutex);
void thread_without_class2(int number, std::mutex &mutex);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::mutex mutex;

    auto threadClass = std::make_unique<ThreadClass>(std::ref(mutex));

    std::thread t1(thread_without_class, std::ref(mutex));
    std::thread t2(thread_without_class2, 10, std::ref(mutex));
    std::thread t3(thread_without_class2, 11, std::ref(mutex));
    std::thread t4([tc = std::move(threadClass)]() {
        tc->numberOfOutputsI = 5;
        tc->ThreadOutput();
    });


    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    return 0;
}


void thread_without_class(std::mutex &mutex){
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << "c++11 thread without anything" << std::endl;
}

void thread_without_class2(int number, std::mutex &mutex){
    for (auto i=0; i<number; i++){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        std::cout << "c++11 thread with function parameter: " << number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

example output:

```
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread without anything
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
I am a class called as a thread
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
I am a class called as a thread
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
I am a class called as a thread
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
I am a class called as a thread
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
I am a class called as a thread
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
c++11 thread with function parameter: 10
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
c++11 thread with function parameter: 11
```

Comment: Thanks std::ref solved my problem with the mutexes but make_unique is c++14 I think.

Comment: @akirahinoshiro you can replace `std::make_unique<T>(std::ref(m));` with `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(m));`

Comment: Your both solutions work fine in VC2015 in VC2012 the lambda makes some trouble.
But what is working is using std::thread t4(&ThreadClass::ThreadOutput, threadClass, 10); with a slightly modified ThreadOutput() to ThreadOutput(int numberOfOutputsI)