# PyQt QMutex in worker and main thread

Tags: pyqt, mutex, qthread

I want to lock the print function with a `QMutex` so only one thread can access it at a time. I wrote a very simple GUI with two buttons, one that quits the thread and one that tries to print something to see if the main thread blocks.

I've gotten it to work by making the lock a global variable but everyone in the internet says global variables are a bad idea. However declaring locks in the `__init__` part of the Main Window and Worker class definitions as `self.lock = QtCore.QMutex()` does not provide the same behavior as when I declare it as a global variable.

What is the proper way to to ensure that the main thread will wait on the worker?

Below is the code for the global case:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import time

lock=QtCore.QMutex()

class expSignals(QtCore.QObject):
# =============================================================================
#   Signal for quitting the thread. Dunno if should be seperate class or stati
#   for main window
# =============================================================================
    pause=QtCore.pyqtSignal()

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
# =============================================================================
#         Create thread,worker, lock and move worker
# =============================================================================
        self.thread=QtCore.QThread(self)
        self.mot=motorpositioner()
        self.mot.moveToThread(self.thread)

# =============================================================================
#         Putting buttons and GUI stuff in place
# =============================================================================
        self.button=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Quit thread',self)
        self.button2=QtWidgets.QPushButton('Test locking',self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.button2.move(0,50)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry( 300, 300, 350, 300 )

# =============================================================================
#         Making and connecting signals
# =============================================================================
        self.qthread_sig=expSignals()
        self.thread.started.connect(self.mot.do_it)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.qthread_sig.pause.emit)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.test_lock)
        self.qthread_sig.pause.connect(self.thread.quit)

# =============================================================================
#         Start Thread
# =============================================================================
        self.thread.start()

# =============================================================================
#       Mutex should lock print
# =============================================================================
    def test_lock(self):
        #global lock
        with QtCore.QMutexLocker(lock):
            print('Printed in main thread')

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.qthread_sig.pause.emit()
        event.accept()

class motorpositioner(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
# =============================================================================
#       Create timer and lock, connect timer to print
# =============================================================================
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(parent=self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.query_mot)
        self.stat=0
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()        
    def do_it(self):
# =============================================================================
#       Start timer
# =============================================================================
        self.timer.start(5000)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def query_mot(self):
        #global lock
        with QtCore.QMutexLocker(lock):
            print('Printed in worker thread')
            time.sleep(5)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() 
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I don't actually want to lock the print function but rather make sure that only one thread at a time talks to a positioning platform controlled from the PC.

Comment: If global variables were always bad it would be impossible to import anything or to declare functions and classes in the module scope. The real code smell comes from ***global state*** that is shared between modules. There is nothing at all wrong with having global variables *per se*, so long as they are treated as being "private" to the module. The usual convention when doing this is to prefix the variables with an underscore.

Comment: @ekhumoro Could I then say that the correct way to handle this would be making the lock global in the scope of the module and making sure that all communication with the piece of hardware (which I want to make sure is always talking to a single thread) is restricted to that module? Also while looking for an answer to this I stumbled across some examples in C++ where you pass a pointer to a mutex created in the main thread [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471955/c11-threads-with-shared-mutex-and-class-instance

Comment: The specific scoping of the variable is something of a red herring here. The real point is that you must use a **single** mutex to lock the resource. From this, it follows that if you have multiple entry points (e.g. two methods in separate classes), then you somehow need to provide a way for each class to access *the same mutex*. A module global variable is one way to do that; another would be a static/class member on one of the classes. Of course, if you have only one entry point for accessing the resource, the scoping of the mutex variable has no relevance at all.